# Difference between "array of double" and TDoubleDynArray

Tags: delphi

The `System.Types` unit declares an array type:

```
TDoubleDynArray  = array of Double;
```

If I declare a method as:

```
procedure func (x : TDoubleDynArray)
```

I notice that the argument `x` acts like a `var` argument, ie I can change `x` inside the method and I'll see the changes reflected outside the method.

However when I use

```
procedure func (x : array of double)
```

As expected, any changes in `x` stays in `func`. Although `TDoubleDynArray` appears to be declared as an `array of double`, it behaves differently from my own `array of double`. What is the explanation for this?

**Update:** I noticed that if I declare my own type `TMyArray = array of double` then I get the same behavior as `TDynamicDynArray`. Is this something to do with a difference between basic array types?

Test code follows

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses System.Types;

var
   x : TDoubleDynArray;
   y : array of double;

procedure func1 (x : TDoubleDynArray);
begin
  x[0] := -999.123;
end;

procedure func2 (y : array of double);
begin
  y[0] := -999.123;
end;

begin
    setLength (x, 10);
    func1 (x);
    writeln ('TDoubleDynArray: ', x[0]);

    setLength (y, 10);
    y[0] := 0;
    func2 (y);
    writeln ('array of double: ', y[0]);

    Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
procedure func1 (x : TDoubleDynArray);
```

The function argument is a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays). That is a reference type. That means that the function argument `x` is a reference to the array. A consequence of that is that changes to the elements of the array inside `func1` change the caller's array.

```
procedure func2 (y : array of double);
```

The function argument is an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters). Although it overloads the `array of` syntax it is quite a different beast from a dynamic array. Because this open array is passed by value, a copy of the array is passed to the function, and so modifications made by the function are not visible to the caller.

It's worth pointing out that, because you passed `y` by value, a copy of the array is passed. That is inefficient, more so for larger arrays. As a rule, by value open arrays should be avoided. Use either `var` or a `const` open array parameters. The same advice applies to other large types, like fixed length arrays and records.

Open array parameters are an endless source of confusion. I recommend that you read the documentation that I linked to, and Rudy's article on the subject: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Comment: One question to add to your answer. If I declare a type TMyArray = array of double and use that type to declare an argument, the argument become a dynamic array?

Comment: Correct. `TMyArray` is a dynamic array.

Comment: @rhody: Using `array of X` *directly* in the parameter declaration creates an **open array**.  *Any* other use of `array of X` creates a **dynamic array** instead.

Comment: Can't just add 'const' to the function parameter to avoid creating a copy?

Comment: @Hans Yes, as stated in the answer