# Pascal - What is the most efficient way to pass an array as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, pascal

This is mostly for dynamic arrays though.
I have known of three ways to pass an array as a parameter by far:

- As a value parameter: this results in the entire array being copied and is considered inefficient by many books (except for [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.3543&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which creates confusion among me).
- As a VAR parameter: this results in only the address of the first element being copied, and is considered optimal by many books, with the drawback of possibility of accidentally changing the array content when you don't need to do so.
- As a pointer: this is something I don't usually see. What is the difference between this and the second method? As for another (possibly) relevant stuff, the [wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array) says that the dynamic array is itself a pointer with automatic dereferencing, so when passing one to a function, shouldn't it be passed as a pointer anyway?

So which method should be used generally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "array of double" and TDoubleDynArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595652/difference-between-array-of-double-and-tdoubledynarray)

Comment: What asd-tm says. It sounds like confusing dynamic arrays and open arrays which share the same syntax in different places. If not, please show some code.

Comment: so if you pass var open array parameter it is the same as defining a dynamic array type and passing an argument of it?